How to reduce very slow startup time of Ignite?
My application uses Ignite as a persistent cache. The machine is fast, the cache folder is on a hard drive. The startup time is ca. 40 seconds. How can I make the startup faster? If subsequent cache access becomes slower, that is fine for me. I just need a quick startup during development.
The configuration (in Kotlin):
IgniteConfiguration().apply {
    metricsLogFrequency = 0
    dataStorageConfiguration = DataStorageConfiguration().apply {
        this.storagePath = storagePath
        defaultDataRegionConfiguration.apply {
            isPersistenceEnabled = true
            maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 1 GiB RAM
        }
    }
}

CacheConfiguration<K, V>(name).apply {
    setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ETERNAL))
    atomicityMode = CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL
}


Try to ensure that you shut down cleanly, that way when it starts, it does not have to replay the transaction log.
However, the real answer is: don't keep shutting down your Ignite server. Run it as a server process (ignite.sh) and have your Kotlin application connect as a client.
